# Ember JS on Rasp PI

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, npm-install

I was trying Ember JS on my RASP Pi. Unfortunately i was unable to proceed with ember installation with my npm due to below error :

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: broccoli-merge-trees@'^2.0.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.3","0.1.4","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","1.0.0","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.1.2","1.1.3","1.1.4","1.1.5","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.2.2","1.2.3","1.2.4","2.0.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.35-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli@2.13"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/Documents/myWorkspace/node-v0.10.2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
```

NPM version currently installed on my pi is :1.2.15

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Ember-cli requires at least Node 4 to compile. But you could do all your Ember work locally and the copy compiled assets to your Pi...

Comment: @acorncom : Thank you for your response. This is exactly the way I am trying to progress.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Node looks like it is too old.

Try installing the latest version of Node by running the following commands:

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb 
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```